# How To allow access to default route in yii2 Advanced Template?

Tags: php, yii2

I need to give access to home page for full access with out login ex http://www.example.com/
but it works when only http://www.example.com/site/index because site/index is set as default route
how to give permission to site/index with out in url in yii2

```
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => ['login','site/index'],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
    'denyCallback' => function () {
        return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);
    },
```

Comment: remove `login` from the `actions` array in the rules

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should include these lines in your config `frontend/config/main.php` in to `components` section:

```
...
'baseUrl' => '/',
...
'request' => [
            //...
            'baseUrl' => '',
            //...
        ],
```

Next is to configure `UrlManager` to react on such request:

```
'rules' => [ 
                '' => 'site/index',
                //...
           ],
```

After that try to go to your http://your_url.local
It should work.

Comment: Hardcoding `baseUrl` may be a bad idea. You will not be able to run this app in subdirectory. Yii should detect correct `baseUrl` for web app, so there should be no reason to hardcode it (it still could make sense for console app).